# SQL injection result

Tags: php, sql, code-injection

Why does this query return the row with id 116:

```
SELECT * 
FROM blahTable
WHERE id =  '116\' OR \'1\'=\'1'
```

The id in the table is 116 but surely it should return 0 rows after that injection code has been added?

Comment: Which injection code? What has the title to do with the question? And yes, if are selecting a row with ID 116, MySQL will return that row if it exists.

Comment: 116' OR '1'='1 with mysql_real_escape string() applied, I thought that was fairly obvious sorry!

Comment: and apologies for the title, i've approved your edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you're asking is that why row with id 116 is returned, when you're running a query that queries for id `'116\' OR \'1\'=\'1'`.

Reason is type conversion. Your string is converted to integer, and to 116, since you're passing it as a string but comparing to an integer. Read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html

A string like 116foofoofoo gets converted to 116 for comparison.

Instead of applying mysql_real_escape_string, you should use methods meant for numbers, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

Because `CAST('116\' OR \'1\'=\'1' AS SIGNED)` or `UNSIGNED` returns 116.